# Deno - Could not target to debug target

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, deno

I have same configuration to run debug for Deno and it run well at Pop OS until it crashed and I installed again Ubuntu 20.04.

Here is my `launch.json`

```
{
  "configurations": [
  {
    "type": "pwa-node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Deno",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.ts",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "/home/transonhoang/.deno/bin/deno",
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "run",
      "--inspect-brk=127.0.0.1:9229",
      "--allow-all",
      "--unstable"
    ],
    "attachSimplePort": 9229
  }
  ]
}
```

When I run debug, the screen will show a popup like image below:

[image]

I really need help on this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you confirm the Demo version you are using? An error that prevented the inspector from starting was introduced in 1.6 and fixed on 1.7

Comment: @StevenGuerrero 1.6.3 now. Thanks for your useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution after figuring out.

1. change `launch.json` to

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Deno",
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "-A",
        "--inspect-brk",
        "--unstable",
        "index.ts"
      ],
      "attachSimplePort": 9229,
      "outputCapture": "std"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Migrate my Deno version to 1.7